# How do you pass local variables to a content_tag or content_for?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, content-for, content-tag

In my view, I have a `content_tag` that looks like so:

```
<% content_tag :div do %>
    <h1><%= title %></h1>
    <p><%= description %></p>
    ... # a bunch of other stuff
<% end %>
```

I'd like to use this `content_tag` multiple times to create "sections" on the page, each time passing a different `title` and `description` to it. However, I don't want to go and make a partial, that seems like overkill. **I want everything to be contained in the one view file**. How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assigning the `content_tag` to a variable (and subsequently printing the variable) seems a bit convoluted, particularly as there's no good way of passing your collection of products to it.

A DRYer way of doing this would be to iterate through your list of products and pass each to your `content_tag`:

```
<% products.each do |product| %>
    <%= content_tag :div, :class => "product-info" do %>
        <h1><%= product.name %></h1>
        <p><%= product.description %></p>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

**Alternatively**, you can abstract this logic into a view helper that effectively produces the same result:

```
def product_info_div(products)
    products.each do |product| %>
        content_tag :div, :class => "product-info" do %>
            content_tag :div, product.name
            content_tag :p, product.description
        end
    end
end
```

In your view, you'd invoke this in the following manner:

```
<%= product_info_div(@products) %>
```

While this isn't a partial, it *is* another file. However, it's also precisely what view helpers are meant to do. Either option will keep your code DRY and readable while accomplishing precisely what you want, IMO.

EDIT:

You don't need to explicitly pass local variables in order to use them within a `content_tag` – they're available for use within the `content_tag` as they'd be outside of it.

Though I'm unsure how you're precisely getting `title` and `description` to vary, you could make a parallel assignment *directly prior* to the `content_tag` declaration in which you assign values to the `title` and `description` local variables:

```
<% title, description = 'title_1', 'description_1' %>
<%= content_tag :div do %>
    <h1><%= title %></h1>
    <p><%= description %></p>
    # a bunch of other stuff
<% end %>

<% title, description = 'title_2', 'description_2' %>
<%= content_tag :div do %>
    <h1><%= title %></h1>
    <p><%= description %></p>
    # a bunch of other stuff
<% end %>
```

Note that you'll need to output the `content_tag` using `<%= %>`. Rails can't do anything with an interpreted `content_tag` if it's not outputted.

Comment: I don't have a list of products, that was a bad example. See my edit.

Comment: Thanks. I guess a view helper function is the way to go. Is there no way to define a function directly inside a view?

Comment: I've never seen it done, and even then, I can't imagine _how_ it'd be done. A view helper works perfectly in this situation, though, because it extracts the logic of a function _away_ from the view (where it really shouldn't be) and _into_ a separate layer.

Comment: If you found this answer useful (as other users evidently have), would you kindly consider accepting it as correct?